# how to use dict inside a plist

Tags: ios, swift

I have a plist file like

```
<dict>
   <key>horse</key>
   <dict>
      <key>level</key>
      <integer>2</integer>
   </dict>
</dict>
```

and I load it by code bellow

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist")
dataBase = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
let array = NSMutableArray()
for member in (dataBase.allKeys) {
    let level = member.valueForKey("level") as! Int
    if () {
        //do something
    }
 }
```

when the app runs, it will crash. The reason I think is that member in the dataBase can't be cast to NSDictionary since it's NSTaggedPointerString, I don't know how to make it work.

**update:**

The previous question, I have addressed the answer by @Wonzigii, and now I got the right dict using this method I defined validateCard(), which is @Wonzigii said bellow.

```
func validateCard() -> NSArray?
```

Now I want to randomly retrieve its item inside the new array to use it to do something, what I'm solving this issue is using a random index, but seem I can't get the array item by index, since if I did so, I can't use it to get the next layer dict. what should I do next?

```
if let avaliableCardDeck = self.validateCard() {
     for _ in 0...16 {
        let maxAvaliableCards = avaliableCardDeck.count
        let index = Int(arc4random()) % maxAvaliableCards
        let cardInfo = avaliableCardDeck[index]
        let newCard = PlayCard()
        newCard.rank = cardInfo.valueForKey("number") as! Int
        newCard.imageName = cardInfo.valueForKey("imageSource") as? String
        addCard(newCard)
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `allKeys` will return an array contains type `AnyObject`.
So yet `member`, in this case, is `AnyObject` type.

```
for member in (dataBase!.allKeys) where member as? String == "horse" {
    let integer = dataBase?.valueForKeyPath("horse.level") as! Int
    print(integer)
}
```

Note that `allKeys` always return top level *keys*.

Edit:

The below code will use `member` as the key to loop through the dictionary  to retrieve deeper value.

```
for member in (dataBase!.allKeys) {
    if let dic = dataBase?.valueForKey(member as! String) {
        // get the level value or something else
        let integer = dic.valueForKey("level") as! Int 
        print(integer)
    }   
}
```

**More Swiftly way(without forced unwrapping, aka, `!`)**:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist"), db = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    for member in db.keys {
        if let dic = db[member] {
            // get the level value or something else
            let integer = dic.valueForKey("level") as! Int
            print(integer)
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think I figured out the crash reason, but I can't find a good way to solve it. Like you mentioned, I think it will work, but only for horse, what I intended is I use allKeys to get a array, and I can call valueForKeyPath for every item inside the array.

Comment: And because the allKeys I get a array with NSTaggedPointerString, the subclass of NSString, which can't respond to the dictionary methods, and cause crash, can I have a better way to cast it back to NSDictionary?

Comment: @Wonzigii I tried with your style, works well now, but Xcode let me add ! to wrapper db.keys and db![member]. My dict is written inside a class, and I give it a Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? type.

Comment: @Ryan You rarely need to make a dictionary optional. Don't add complexity if you don't need it. ;)

Comment: @EricD I do make my dictionary optional, as my previous comment, class CardDataBase {
    var dataBase: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?       But the code still needs me to add a !

Comment: @Ryan Eric means you don't need to make it optional. Just remove the ？

Comment: OK I get it, now my code runs successfully, and I do I have another question, the previous step I got the right dict item from the whole dict, let's say 2, the next step I want to random retrieve the available item inside the new dict, since I have make dict type to [String, AnyObject], seems I have no way to retrieve it by index,

Comment: options1: add all values to an array and retrieve random index options2: use an array instead of a dictionay for you data struct

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. If the path and all are correct this code must work, or else it will not execute. Will surely not crash

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") else {
    return
}
if let dataBase = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path), member = dataBase["horse"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let level = member["level"] as? Int {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Edit: Giving a generic one

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") else {
            return 
}
if let dataBase = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
    for (_, value) in dataBase {
        if value is [String: AnyObject], let level = value["level"] as? Int {
            //do something
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: can we have more generic guard style since the horse is just an example, I have more items, they are the same with the horse which I will use them all.

Comment: Edited the answer and added a more generic traversal